# Laravel 5.3 - QueryException in Connection.php line 761

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I keep getting this error:

> (General error: 1366) Incorrect integer value

every time I try to post my form with these specific columns below:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('dossiers', function (Blueprint $table) {             
        $table->integer('amount_of_cilinders')->nullable();         
        $table->integer('amount_of_doors')->nullable();            
        $table->integer('manufacturing_year')->nullable();          
        $table->integer('manufacturing_month')->nullable();
        $table->date('date_first_admission')->nullable();                         
        $table->integer('weight')->nullable();                                            
        $table->integer('power')->nullable();      
    });
}
```

Despite having all my columns set to nullable, SQL asks me to fill in an integer/date in the inputs.

What goes wrong here?

Comment: What are you posting to your form? It sounds like you're posting a non-integer to those fields. Could it be a string or decimal?

Comment: I think you're trying to enter a non-integer data into the column.

Comment: Post the code where you're inserting the form results into your table/model.   What you have here just means we're just guessing, and the kids broke my crystal ball.

Comment: @aynber Do you mean where I call the $table->propertyname (show)?

Comment: Yes, where you do `$table->amount_of_cilinders = ...` that whole bit.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to post an non-integer value to the column through your form. I'd suggest checking the data that's being passed from the form.

Comment: Basically, SQL doesn't allow me to post this form without filling in an integer in the input fields (view). I find this weird, because all my columns are set to nullable. Am I clear?

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'd check that the column is actually nullable in the SQL.